# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. Метод find не находит тег <tbody>

Tags: php, парсер

Добрый день.
Есть следующий код php:

```
require_once "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('<table><tbody class="my-class">text text text</tbody></table>');
$text = $html->find('tbody',0)->innertext;
echo $text;
```

на выходе не получаю ничего. То есть тег  не находится.
Заменяем tbody на thead:

```
require_once "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('<table><thead class="my-class">text text text</thead> </table>');
$text = $html->find('thead',0)->innertext;
echo $text;
```

и все работает:
выводит "text text text"

так же все работает если поиск производить по классу тега

```
require_once "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('<table><tbody class="my-class">text text text</tbody></table>');
$text = $html->find('.my-class',0)->innertext;
echo $text;
```

выводит "text text text"

Вопрос: что в первом случае я делаю не так?

Comment: вы в целом все делаете так. Почему не получается - смотрите 701-ю строку кода `simple_html_dom.php`, а вот зачем оно так сделано надо гуглить.

Comment: в зависимости от версии номер строки может быть и другой, но строка следующая: `if ($m[1]==='tbody') continue;` В целом можете ее закомментировать и будет работать, однако надо понимать, что подобный код не просто так там появился.

Comment: спасибо большое!